# Android volley memory leak

Tags: android, android-volley

I have a service that use images from internal memory and updates them from the server.

My problem is that the simple fact of making an image request like this*, generates a small memory leak, which accumulates until the app crashes :(

Could anyone tell me how to get ride of it? Is it an issue of Cache?

My service is called every X time by alarm Manager.

[image]

```
    public void overwrite(final String urlImage, final int position ) {
    ImageRequest request = new ImageRequest(urlImage, //from URL matrix
            new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Bitmap bitmap) {
                    System.out.println("SERVER_WALL GO--->> got overwrite Bitmap ");
                    }
                }
            }, 0, 0, null,
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    System.out.println("SERVER_WALL --->> : Error ");
                }
            });
    queue.add(request);
    return ;
}
```

Comment: Do you keep references to those bitmaps which were loaded?

Comment: Take a look at HeapViewer in Android Device Monitor. It will help you to track all the allocations and see if there is no memory leak. https://developer.android.com/tools/performance/heap-viewer/index.html

Comment: The Service is started after broadcast alarm (AlarmManager), and then killed, so the memory leak survive the service (and with the service, ALL inner references are erased). There is something with volley, I'm sure..

Comment: @Dimitri , I was checking it, but can't do the step 4. , I click my app when appearing under the DeviceName, but nothing happen..

Comment: Make sure your app is launched in the device and selects it in the app list

Comment: I launch it in the emulator. I have emulator in developer mode, debugg, see the apps under ["Device"] but nothing happen when I click the app...